# cURL HTTPS not working after cross compilation

Tags: c++, https, openssl, cross-compiling, libcurl

I'm using cURL on Ubuntu to request API with HTTPS and everything works fine with Ubuntu packages installed.
As I want to cross-compile this application I've build zLib, OpenSSL & cURL staticly.

How I compiled zLib :

```
CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ./configure --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --static
make && sudo make install
```

How I compiled OpenSSL :

```
CROSS_COMPILE="x86_64-w64-mingw32-" ./Configure -DHAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC -lz -lws2_32 zlib mingw64 --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32
make && sudo make install
```

How I compiled cURL :

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-optimize --with-ssl=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-shared
make && sudo make install
```

I got no errors and cURL configure output show SSL & zLib enabled.

I compile my application with this command line :

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ Dev/C++/Projets/wxTrainning/*.cpp -static  $(curl-win --cflags --static-libs) -lpthread -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

**curl-win** is an alias to curl-config in my build folder.
Here are the outputs of :

**curl-win --cflags**

```
-DCURL_STATICLIB -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
```

**curl-win --static-libs**

```
 /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libcurl.a -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/usr/x86_64-w64- 
 mingw32/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lwldap32 -lz -lws2_32
```

**curl-win --libs**

```
-L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lwldap32 -lz -lws2_32
```

**curl-win --configure**

```
'--prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32' '--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32' '--with-ssl=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32' '--disable-shared' 'host_alias=x86_64-w64-mingw32'
```

So, my problem is :

When I compile on Linux everything is OK and I can use HTTPS, I got the response.
But when I cross-compile and launch it with wine, HTTPS does not work anymore. I can get a response from a basic HTTP request but never with HTTPS. I always get 0 return code. It looks like SSL is not enabled but the configuration tell me everything is ok.

I am completely lost.. If anyone can help I would appreciate it.
Thanks, Laurent.

**EDIT :**
It's working without using secure SSL & TLS as precised in comment

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS, 0);
```

**SOLVED :**

I got this working by copying the public key of my SSL certificate and telling cURL to use it with :

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cert.pem");
```

Comment: Completely disabling the certificate checks is not *fixing the TLS*, it is more like *removing all security from the TLS connections*.

Comment: Hi @DanielStenberg,
I understand perfectly, but it's the only way to make cURL work on Windows.
I'm still looking why the SSL is not working.